# IntelliJ Plugin Development: how to generate a new source file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

I'm working on a plugin which will generate code inside and outside of the opened class.

I extended `GenerateMembersHandlerBase` class to generate members of the class - it works quite fine.

Now I need to generate a full class (new source file) which will be placed aside from the class I working on.

**Problem:** I can't find any API that would allow me to create new java source file. Please hint me the API, or hint me the place in [IntelliJ IDEA source code](https://github.com/joewalnes/idea-community) where such thing is implemented.

**More context:** Let's say we have `com.mycompany.User` class. I'm implementing a plugin that will generate a constructor for it with the next format:

```
public User(UserInfo info) {
    //...
}
```

And the `UserInfo` class needs to be generated on the flight.
So after code generation, I should have a constructor in class `User` and separate source file for `com.mycompany.UserInfo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a new virtual file using `VirtualFile.createChildData()` method.

An example of how IDEA itself creating files can be found in [NewFileAction.createNewFile()](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/173.4591/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/fileChooser/actions/NewFileAction.java) method.

It's calling the [FileSystemTreeImpl.createNewFile()](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/173.4591/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/fileChooser/ex/FileSystemTreeImpl.java) method which calling the aforementioned `createChildData()` method.